# "ENOSPC: no space left on device" when there is free space on fuse NTFS-3G

Tags: mount, hard-drive, filesystem, ntfs, fuse

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to run a command that involves creating a lot of files in the cache directory: `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`. I have set this variable to `/media/michael/Storage2/cache/`, in order to force the cache to be installed here instead of into my Linux partition.

The disk in question has plenty of remaining space and inodes:

```
$ df /media/michael/Storage2/
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1      1953512444 843210596 1110301848  44% /media/michael/Storage2
$ df -i /media/michael/Storage2/
Filesystem         Inodes   IUsed      IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1      1115872408 5527524 1110344884    1% /media/michael/Storage2
```

However, when I run the command in question (`pre-commit run --all-files`, which involves running an `npm install` to install node packages), I get the following error:

```
23065 verbose stack Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, mkdir '/media/michael/Storage2/cache/pre-commit/repo822s6gpl/node_modules/.staging/deep-is-660143e4'
23066 verbose cwd /media/michael/Storage2/cache/pre-commit/repo822s6gpl
23067 verbose Linux 4.19.34-041934-generic
23068 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/home/michael/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.0/bin/npm" "install"
23069 verbose node v14.13.1
23070 verbose npm  v6.14.6
23071 error code ENOSPC
23072 error syscall mkdir
23073 error path /media/michael/Storage2/cache/pre-commit/repo822s6gpl/node_modules/.staging/deep-is-660143e4
23074 error errno -28
23075 error nospc ENOSPC: no space left on device, mkdir '/media/michael/Storage2/cache/pre-commit/repo822s6gpl/node_modules/.staging/deep-is-660143e4'
23076 error nospc There appears to be insufficient space on your system to finish.
23076 error nospc Clear up some disk space and try again.
23077 verbose exit [ -28, true ]
```

The most unusual thing about this drive is that it's using NTFS via NTFS-3G (FUSE):

```bsh
df -T /media/michael/Storage2/
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc1      fuseblk 1953512444 843220496 1110291948  44% /media/michael/Storage2
lsblk -no name,fstype /dev/sdc1
sdc1 ntfs
```

What could be going wrong to cause a no space error, when this is not the case?

---

Extra Info:

```bsh
$ grep Storage2 /etc/mtab
/dev/sdc1 /media/michael/Storage2 fuseblk rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

Comment: Is it mounted Read Only (`ro`)? `grep Storage2 /etc/mtab`

Comment: No, it's definitely not. I can write to it normally. `/dev/sdc1 /media/michael/Storage2 fuseblk rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0`

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read, ignored by AskUbuntu's indexing system, and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all docker containers on your system share the same disk space.
--I found two solutions:--

1 => Go into Docker Desktop's settings and increase the amount of disk space available.

2 => Run docker container prune to free disk space being used by stopped containers.

In my case I had a bunch stopped docker containers from months back taking up all of the disk space allocated to Docker.